# How to detect words within other words in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

So far I can detect words within phrases. For instance, if the user types "pork", an item called "Cooked Pork" will be returned. However, if the user enters "pork", an item like "pork*" will NOT be returned.

This is how I am comparing my arrays and catching out words within phrases:

```
  for (NSString *allergicITem in matchAgainstArray)
{
    NSString *lowerString = [allergicITem lowercaseString];
    if ([theLowerCellString rangeOfString:lowerString].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

My question is how I can fix this so it will detect the word even if it has a small extension like a " * " in the word " pork* ".

Ok in very simple words this is what I want:

If one array has the word "pork" in it

And another array has the work "pork*"

I want the word "pork*" to be detected and returned.

My code is NOT returning "pork*", hence why I'm asking this question.

If there needs to be any more clarification do let me know.

UPDATE:

I have two table views populated by two separate arrays. One array is populating a table view filled with ingredients that are undesirable to the user, and another array is populating a table view filled with ingredients of a food item. If one of the ingredients of the food item **is the same** as one of the undesirable items, it will be marked red.

So if a food has the following ingredients:

- water
- salt
- chicken*

And the user has populated his "undesirable ingredient" table view like so:

- peanuts
- chicken
- gluten

When the ingredients table view gets displayed, the "chicken*" object should be marked red.

UPDATE 2:

Code proving my point (which all of you can test):
   NSMutableArray *badIng = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *totalIng = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
[badIng addObject:@"Chicken"];
[badIng addObject:@"gluten"];

[totalIng addObject:@"Chicken*"];
[totalIng addObject:@"water"];


for (NSString *badItem in badIng)
{
    NSString *lowerbadString= [badItem lowercaseString];
    NSString *totalString = [totalIng objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *totalLowerString = [totalString lowercaseString];

    if ([totalLowerString rangeOfString:lowerbadString].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Here is the object: %@", badItem);
    }

    else

    {
        NSLog(@"We didn't find it");
    }

}
```

Comment: You enter " cooked pork " and search for " pork ".  (Note the blanks.)  Then " pork " will not get a hit on " porkupine " (if you will allow me that contrived example).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Why is this closed as a duplicate? The OP is already using the code in the duplicate (roughly). Obviously there is an issue specific to this question. Simply closing as a duplicate isn't going to help the OP solve the problem with their code.

Comment: If `lowerCellString`'s value is `@"pork*"`, then `[lowerCellString rangeOfString:@"pork"]` will return `(NSRange){.location=0, .length=4}`. I may have closed this wrongly, but I don't get what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: That "duplicate" isn't.

Comment: @rmaddy: Agreed, I think I screwed up and picked the wrong duplicate, but I'm really not sure what the problem is, because `rangeOfString:` _will_ find `@"pork"` in `@"pork*"`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - He *does not* want "pork" to match "pork*", but *does* want it to match "cooked pork" (the case difference was irrelevant).

Comment: @JoshCaswell No worries. The other 99% of the duplicates you find are a service to us all.

Comment: Thanks for saying that, @rmaddy; I appreciate it.

Comment: (This is an example of where the one-vote close is a bad idea.)

Comment: @HotLicks: but rmaddy or I (or any other gold badge holder) can likewise reopen with a single vote.

Comment: @HotLicks: So the issue is that only _trailing_ characters should not match?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I would assume leading or trailing.  As my first comment (which probably got lost in the noise) suggests.

Comment: Waitaminnit, @HotLicks, on re-reading -- the last sentence says "How can I fix this so it **will detect** the word even if it has a small extension...".

Comment: That is bizarre, since that is the default behavior.

Comment: Oh dear, did not realize I was so unclear. I'm making an edit to the question.

Comment: I beg leave to point out that I said that earlier, @HotLicks. :p

Comment: Aaaand now I'm banned from asking any more questions. Thank you Stack Overflow community.

Comment: This is still unclear. Which string is which? `@"pork"` will be found in `@"pork*"`, but [not the other way around](https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/dc3e19bd45ad5fde509f). Please put up a [_fully runnable_ example that demonstrates the problem you have](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself at the risk of repeating myself, `@"chicken"` _will_ be found by `rangeOfString:` in `@"chicken*"`. At the risk of repeating myself, `@"chicken"` _will_ be found by `rangeOfString:` in `@"chicken*"`. At the risk of repeating myself repeating myself, `@"chicken"` _will_ be found _will be found_ by `rangeOfString:` in `@"chicken*"`. If you're seeing a different result, you need to post code _which everyone can run_ that demonstrates that.

Comment: Clearly describing your problem is not only necessary to get others to understand it, it's also necessary for you to understand it yourself.

Comment: Alright, I added the basic code for testing

Comment: OK, after your edit it's obvious that I was wrong to criticize Josh for closing as a dupe.  You lower-case the search term, but not the item being searched.  How do you expect this to work???

Comment: fixed it, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Make your list like this:

```
" cooked pork "
" roast beef "
" candied yams "
" porkupine "
```

(Note the leading/trailing blanks.)

Then use `" pork "` to search the above list.  `" cooked pork "` will match, `" porkupine "` will not.

Answer (score -1):

Wow, it seems as though I have found a better method to do this. Because I am using iOS 8, I did this:

```
if ([theLowerCellString containsString:lowerString])
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

Now it's working like a charm, and returning the objects that I need.

Comment: The code you posted _does not display_ the problem you say it does. I added one line above the loop to print out the two items. Here's the console output: `2014-10-15 01:46:53.954 MatchWordsWithAsterisks[60753:303] Looking for 'Chicken' in 'chicken*'
2014-10-15 01:46:53.955 MatchWordsWithAsterisks[60753:303] Here is the object: Chicken
2014-10-15 01:46:53.956 MatchWordsWithAsterisks[60753:303] Looking for 'gluten' in 'chicken*'
2014-10-15 01:46:53.956 MatchWordsWithAsterisks[60753:303] We didn't find it` Notice that `rangeOfString:` _found_ 'chicken' in 'chicken*'.